# Combining/overriding 'time-span' rule and 'move-to' rule in Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, rules, email-filter

I already have 2 rules that move all emails from a 'x' and 'z' sender to an 'xyz stuff' subfolder with "stop processing rules" set for them. Now I created another rule that moves all emails received during my holiday to a "holiday" subfolder, but when I tested it, every email that came from 'x' and 'z' during the holiday timespan was also moved to the "holiday" folder. I want the emails from 'x' and 'z' to keep being put into 'xyz stuff' folder during the holiday too, and only the other emails to be put into the "holiday" folder. Is this possible, please?

Answer (score 0):

How did you set the holiday rule?

If you haven't tried to set the rule via OOF rule, it's recommeded to test with it. According to my experience, the rules in OOF wouldn't affect the rules created in "Rules and Alerts", or you could create 2 rules in OOF directly and set the "do not process other" in first rule there(File>Automatic Replies)
[image]